# How to setup xampp, phpunit, ant, zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, ant, build-process, phpunit

First post here, so take it easy please.

I'm working through the first chapter of Zend Framework 1.8 Web Application Development by Keith Pope in an effort to learn PHP and the MVC framework.

I thought I included all the paths correctly and installed PHPUnit 3.3 correctly as well as Zend 1.8 and 1.7.4 Xampp. with Ant version 1.8.2. However, I can't seem to get the first simplest build to build.

From looking at other q's and a's on this site I can tell some of the calls in the build.xml file for PHPunit aren't correct and I've tried to correct them, but now I'm getting the error that C:\xampp\htdocs\zendStoreFront/library/Zend does not exist and when I add the Zend directory in I get lots and lots of errors which is telling me that's probably not the right answer.

I understand there's a lot going on in the whole project and I'm willing to take the time to learn, but one question- On the line that says "   --log-xml ${basedir}/build/logs/phpunit.xml ", is this file expected to be in this directory already, or does the build process create the file? On some attempts an error that's echo'd back say that file doesn't exist and currently there is no file in that directory.

Thanks,

hestes

```
cmd line output
*****************


C:\xampp\htdocs\zendStoreFront\build>ant
Buildfile: C:\xampp\htdocs\zendStoreFront\build\build.xml

buildPreparation:

    getProps:
     [echo] ---- Build Properties ----
     [echo]
     [echo] OS is Windows XP
     [echo] Basedir is C:\xampp\htdocs\zendStoreFront
     [echo] Property file is C:\xampp\htdocs\zendStoreFront/build/ant.properties

     [echo] Script-suffix is .bat
     [echo]
     [echo] ---- Storefront Properties ----
     [echo]
     [echo] Environment is development

configure:
     [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\xampp\htdocs\zendStoreFront\application

test:
     [exec] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
     [exec] PHPUnit 3.3.10 by Sebastian Bergmann.
     [exec]
     [exec] C:\xampp\htdocs\zendStoreFront/library/Zend does not exist

BUILD FAILED
C:\xampp\htdocs\zendStoreFront\build\build.xml:28: exec returned: 1

Total time: 1 second

C:\xampp\htdocs\zendStoreFront\build>cd ..

C:\xampp\htdocs\zendStoreFront>ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010
```

**Build.xml File**

```
<target name="getProps">
   <property file="${basedir}/build/ant.properties" />

   <condition property="script-suffix" value=".bat" else="">
        <os family="windows" />
   </condition>

   <echo message="---- Build Properties ----" />
   <echo message="" />

   <echo message="OS is ${os.name}" />
   <echo message="Basedir is ${basedir}" />
   <echo message="Property file is ${basedir}/build/ant.properties" />
   <echo message="Script-suffix is ${script-suffix}" />

   <echo message="" />
   <echo message="---- Storefront Properties ----" />
   <echo message="" />

   <echo message="Environment is ${environment}" />    

</target>

<target name="test" depends="getProps">
   <exec dir="${basedir}/tests" executable="phpunit${script-suffix}" failonerror="true">
      <arg line="--colors --coverage-html ${basedir}/build/report
         --log-xml ${basedir}/build/logs/phpunit.xml 
         --log-pmd ${basedir}/build/logs/phpunit.pmd.xml
         --log-metrics ${basedir}/build/logs/phpunit.metrics.xml
         --coverage-clover ${basedir}/build/logs/phpunit.coverage.xml 
         AllTests.php"/>
   </exec>
</target>

<target name="configure" depends="getProps">
   <copy file="${basedir}/application/application.php.dist"
         tofile="${basedir}/application/application.php" overwrite="true" />
   <replace file="${basedir}/application/application.php" token="@ENVIRONMENT@" value="${environment}" />
</target>

<target name="buildPreparation">
    <mkdir dir="${basedir}/build/logs" />
    <mkdir dir="${basedir}/build/report" />
</target>

<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${basedir}/build/logs" />
    <delete dir="${basedir}/build/report" />
</target>

<target name="build" depends="buildPreparation,configure,test"/>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add the folder and post the errors you get by updating this question

Comment: Thanks John, the build directory is located: C:\xampp\htdocs\zendStoreFront\build. The error I'm currently getting is posted in the command line output. Thanks by the way for reformatting my post.

Comment: You're welcome. What happens when you create the`C:\xampp\htdocs\zendStoreFront/library/Zend` folder?

Comment: John, when I add the Zend folder in the library folder I get a lengthy printout of echos and exec's which I can paste if you want but at the bottom of the command line it says      [exec]     
BUILD FAILED
C:\xampp\htdocs\zendStoreFront\build\build.xml:28: exec returned: 255 I'm usin

Comment: Cut myself off, I was saying I'm using PHPUnit 3.3.10, ZF 1.10.8, ant 1.8, and the tutorial from "Zend Framework 1.8 Web Application Development: Design, Develop, and Deploy Feature-Rich PHP Web Applications with This MVC Framework" by Keith Pope.

Comment: Hmm, I haven't actually worked with Ant in any depth, so can't really comment on the returns. My suggestion would be to strip everything out and start anew with the build script and iteratively add more commands to it till you hit a stumbling block. At least then you'll know where you're going wrong

Comment: Make sure the logs folder exists. All those listed files in the logs directory should be created by PHPUnit, but PHPUnit is saying that `C:\xampp\htdocs\zendStoreFront/library/Zend` doesn't exist. PHP shouldn't have a problem with \ vs. / so that shouldn't be it. It also complains about a path being wrong.

Comment: One thing to try is to remove Ant from the picture. Execute these commands on the command line outside of Ant. Heck, for PHPUnit you just need to be in the folder that contains `AllTests.php` and type `phpunit AllTests.php`. See what happens with that.

Comment: Thanks guys for the comments, I just noticed them (2 hour later) since I neglected to notice the link saying there are more comments. I'll give these suggestions a go.